# Solution Check: Determine if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_X e^{-nf(x)} d\mu(x) $ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I would appreciate if I could get this proposed solution checked for correctness and rigor. Here is the question:

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu) $ be a finite measure space. Let $f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty) $ be measurable. If the following limit exists, determine its value:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_X e^{-nf(x)} d\mu(x). $$

If it does not, explain. In either case, justify your claims.

Here is my solution:

Since f is a non negative function notice that
$$ e^{-nf(x)} \leq e^{-n(0)} =e^0 =1.$$

Since $X $ is a finite measure space we have
$$ \int_X 1 d\mu(x)= \mu(X) <\infty$$

Therefore by the Dominated Convergence theorem we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_X e^{-nf(x)} = \int_X \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  e^{-nf(x)} .$$

Notice if $ f(x) = 0$, then
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{-nf(x)} = 1$$
and is zero otherwise. In particular we have
$$ \int_X \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  e^{-nf(x)} = \mu(\{x\in X : f(x)=0\})$$
which is finite and therefore the limit exists.

[Edited after taking a limit incorrectly]

Comment: It is true that the dominated convergence theorem is applicable to this problem. However, you made mistake when computing the limit. Note that, for each given number $a \in [0, \infty)$, the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-na}$$ can be computed and its value does depend on $a$. (Q: What is the limit as a function of $a$?) Knowing this, now you should also be able to find the pointwise limit of $e^{-nf(x)}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Review your proof ... the correct answer seems to be that the limit is:  $\mu(x: f(x) = 0)$

Comment: Oh, I see the mistake I have made... silly. Also, does SE frown upon posting solutions like this? Just curious since this question got downvoted immediately

Comment: Don't worry, your question seem perfectly fine to me. :) I am also curious why your question is downvoted.

Comment: Ok, good to know. I am studying for an analysis qual and getting feedback is especially helpful right now. Hopefully I have corrected my earlier mistake as well.